# actualizado números primos gemelos

Tags: c, números-primos

Primos gemelos: son dos números primos y la diferencia entre ellos es de 2.ej:(13 y 11)

El ejercicio tiene que tener al menos dos funciones aparte de la función `main`, y debe funcionar en un ciclo hasta que el usuario indique que desea salir del programa.

Bueno ya actualice el código, ya esta casi  terminado lo que me falta es que al pasar `a` y `b` por `pa` si alguno es no primo y el otro primo la salida es `x` es no primo y no son números primos gemelos. como puedo hacer para que cuando alguno de los dos números sean no primos no me de como salida si son primos gemelos o no.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pa(int x){
    int i, cont=0;
    for(i=1;i<=x;i++){
        if(x%i==0){
            cont = cont+1;
        }
    }
    if(cont>2){
        printf( "\n%d es no primo \n",x );
    }
    else{
        int d,b,a;
        d = b-a;
        if(d==2){
            printf("\n Son numeros primos gemelos \n");
        }
        else{
            printf("\n No son numeros primos gemelos \n");

        }
        return 0;
    }
    return x;
}



int main(){
    int r,a,b,f,j,k;
    k = 0;
    while(k==0){
        printf("\n Ingrese primer digito: \n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("\n Ingrese segundo digito: \n");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        if(a>0 &&b>0 &&a!=b){
            r = pa(a);
            j = pa(b);
        }
        else{
            if (a==b){
                printf("Los numeros son iguales.");
            }
            else{
                printf("los numeros no son correctos");
                return 0;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto es sencillo y de paso aprendes cómo va lo de probar y mantener código. Identifica datos de prueba que sean válidos. Tienes 13 y 11, busca otros pocos ejemplos. Luego úsalos en tu programa y revisa que el resultado sea el esperado (que sí son). Luego usa números al azar que no sean primos gemelos, siempre los mismos pares de datos, revisando que la respuesta sea que no son. Si te falla con alguno de esos casos, puedes revisar y/o preguntarnos por qué ese caso no funciona. Decir "no sé si funciona" no suena bien y es una pregunta muy amplia. Ánimo que vas bien.

Comment: No necesitas `pa` y `pb`. Ambas son el mismo código; sólo cambia el nombre de la variable. Elimina `pb` y reemplazala con llamadas a `pa`

Answer (score 1):

El enunciado es muy claro y explícito, el código necesita al menos dos funciones.

Es muy importante saber dividir algoritmos complejos en unidades lógicas simples, ya que así consigues funciones sencillas y fáciles de probar.

En tu caso una opción que parece bastante lógica sería:

- función que comprueba si dos números son primos gemelos
- función que comprueba si un número dado es primo

Como ves, la primera función se apoya en la segunda para poder cumplir con su cometido.

¿Y esto cómo se hace?

La función que verifica si un número es primo es trivial... ya tienes el código hecho:

```
int es_primo(int numero)
{
  if( numero <= 0 )
    return 0;

  int cont=0;
  for(int i=1;i<=numero;i++){
    if(numero%i==0){
      cont = cont+1;
    }
  }

  return (cont == 2);
}
```

Como ves, la función aglutina parte del código de `pa` (por favor, de ahora en adelante usa nombres que tengan sentido tanto para las funciones como para las variables) y parte del `main`.

La función devolverá `0` si el número no es correcto (es menor o igual a 0) o si no es primo y `1` cuando el número sea primo.

Ahora vamos a mirar la primera función. Está claro que para verificar si dos números son primos gemelos, la función debe recibir dos parámetros. Lo que tiene que hacer entonces la función es comprobar que los números sean primos y que su distancia sea exactamente 2:

```
int son_primos_gemelos(int a, int b)
{
  if( es_primo(a) && es_primo(b))
  {
    if( a > b )
    {
      return a - b == 2;
    }
    else
    {
      return b - a == 2;
    }
  }

  return 0; // al menos uno de los dos numeros no es primo   
}
```

El `if` aprovecha una característica del lenguaje, y es que el valor 0 se evalúa como falso, mientras que el resto se evalúan como verdaderos, es decir, el condicional requiere que las dos llamadas a `es_primo` devuelvan `1`.